# error with sending mail vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

i'm having a problem with sending mail. my code is so easy as below.
when this code starts it gives the error:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

when i searched for this error, they recommend changing web.config trust full setting or port from 587 to 25 and other stuff, but none work. what else could it be?

```
Sub MailGonder()
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    SmtpServer.Host = "mail.excelinefendisi.com"
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("info@excelinefendisi.com", "mypassword")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    mail.From = New MailAddress("info@excelinefendisi.com")
    mail.To.Add("volkan.yurtseven@hotmail.com")
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)

End Sub
```

Comment: please specify whole exception.

Comment: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, work perfect for me :

```
Dim iphost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim Emailmessage As New MailMessage()
    Emailmessage.From = New MailAddress("from_Email@hotmail.com")
    Emailmessage.To.Add("To_Email@hotmail.com")
    Emailmessage.Subject = "tTest Mail"
    Emailmessage.Body = ("This is for testing SMTP")
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("your_email@hotmail.com.com", "Password")
    smtp.Send(Emailmessage)
```